# Numeric error when attempting to use rbind

Tags: r, rbind

I'm attempting to create an extra row at the bottom of the below df that creates a total for each column. This was done using `rbind(Men_15, colSums(Men_15[1:52,])`. However, given the first couple of rows are factor and not numeric, I get the error message, "'x' must be numeric". How can I get R to ignore the irrelevant columns and sum just the numeric columns?
I also want to name the row "USA"

```
   structure(list(State = structure(1:52, .Label = c("Alabama", 
"Alaska", "Arizona", "Arkansas", "California", "Colorado", "Connecticut", 
"Delaware", "District of Columbia", "Florida", "Georgia", "Hawaii", 
"Idaho", "Illinois", "Indiana", "Iowa", "Kansas", "Kentucky", 
"Louisiana", "Maine", "Maryland", "Massachusetts", "Michigan", 
"Minnesota", "Mississippi", "Missouri", "Montana", "Nebraska", 
"Nevada", "New Hampshire", "New Jersey", "New Mexico", "New York", 
"North Carolina", "North Dakota", "Ohio", "Oklahoma", "Oregon", 
"Pennsylvania", "Puerto Rico", "Rhode Island", "South Carolina", 
"South Dakota", "Tennessee", "Texas", "Utah", "Vermont", "Virginia", 
"Washington", "West Virginia", "Wisconsin", "Wyoming"), class = "factor"), 
    Men = c(2341093L, 384160L, 3299088L, 1451913L, 19087135L, 
    2648667L, 1751607L, 448413L, 306674L, 9600009L, 4883331L, 
    709871L, 810464L, 6316899L, 3235263L, 1534595L, 1439862L, 
    2164208L, 2261156L, 650081L, 2872643L, 3249650L, 4861973L, 
    2692166L, 1451723L, 2964003L, 510163L, 929606L, 1407735L, 
    653484L, 4343027L, 1032414L, 9541801L, 4795408L, 367963L, 
    5662893L, 1906944L, 1948453L, 6245344L, 1713860L, 510388L, 
    2322409L, 423477L, 3167756L, 13171316L, 1459229L, 308573L, 
    4060948L, 3487725L, 913631L, 2851385L, 295561L)), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -52L))
```

Comment: Try: `Men_15$State <- as.character(Men_15$State); rbind(Men_15, c("USA", sum(Men_15$Men)))`

Answer (score 0):

You get the error from `colSums` because your first column is not numeric.

To add "USA" in column state you can convert it with `as.character`. In this case you can simply use `sum` to get the sum of column `men`.

```
Men_15$State <- as.character(Men_15$State)
Men_15 <- rbind(Men_15, list("USA", sum(Men_15$Men)))
tail(Men_15)
#           State       Men
#48      Virginia   4060948
#49    Washington   3487725
#50 West Virginia    913631
#51     Wisconsin   2851385
#52       Wyoming    295561
#53           USA 157448140
```

To get `colSums` only form `numeric` columns you have to test them with `is.numeric` like:

```
colSums(Men_15[sapply(Men_15, is.numeric)])
#      Men 
#157448140
```